# Conditional Formatting ( Color Coding) a date field

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, date-time, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am using the JSON Script below to create a list where records with Expiration date 10 days from @now will highlight RED; 20 Days from @ now will Highlight Yellow, and 60 Days From @ now will highlight Golden.

10 days & 20 days work. The 60 days does not. I edited an existing and changed only the milliseconds.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(@currentField <= @now + 864000000,'sp-field-severity--blocked', if(@currentField <= @now + 2592000000, 'sp-field-severity--warning', if(@currentfield <= @now + 5184000000, 'sp-field-severity--good', 'sp-field-severity--good')))"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(@currentField <= @now + 1814400000,'Error', '')"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your milliseconds for 20 days are not correct, it should be 1728000000 (86400000 *20).
After correcting it, I'm getting the below output. Is that the expected outcome?

[image]

Updating the response to show different color for days > 60
Please note that there is no [predefined classes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting), so had to use background-color style

**Updated JSON** (if statement has been rearranged)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField>@now + 5184000000,'#b5e7a0', if((@currentField >=@now + 1728000000) && (@currentField <@now + 5184000000) , '#d4ac6e',if((@currentField >=@now + 864000000) && (@currentField < @now + 1728000000), '#ffef96', '#f7cac9')))",
    "color": "black",
    "font-size": "1.25em"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(@currentField <= @now + 1814400000,'Error', '')"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: the value at 60 days from @now I want  to be golden to distinguish  from the Green - GOOD value at 63 days

Comment: You mean, if >60, you want it to be a different color, right? Maybe greener, right?  Let me see if there are any default class that we can use for that

Comment: Basically if at 60 days to be a darker yellow - golden - the at 10 days is red and at 20 is yellow - the at 60 is still green   - MANY thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Fed 15 is 60 days out from today but still green

Comment: Updated my post. Let know if you have any questions

Answer (score 2):

This is the formula to calculate days in Milliseconds

```
days in Milliseconds = Number of days * (24*60*60*1000)
```

So for 60 days, it should be `5184000000`

But I think the issue is not related to Milliseconds, it's related to the condition itself where you should use && to define the period of time as the following:

**Example**

For 60 days, you have to check if the current date greater than 20 days and lower than or equal to 60 days.

```
If((@currentField <=@now + 5184000000) && (@currentField > @now + 1728000000))
```

Also, you should do the same for 20 days

```
If((@currentField <=@now + 1728000000) && (@currentField > @now + 864000000))
```

And finally, for 10 days, it should be

```
If((@currentField <=@now + 864000000)
```

> Read more details about the complete JSON date from at **[JSON SharePoint Date Column Formatting in SharePoint 2019 and SharePoint Online](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-date-column-formatting/)**

Answer (score 1):

You got the capitalization wrong.@currentField F is uppercase, the lowercase f of your last if.
[image]

The number of milliseconds in 20 days is 1728000000.

Updated json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(@currentField <= @now + 864000000,'sp-field-severity--blocked', if(@currentField <= @now + 2592000000, 'sp-field-severity--warning', if(@currentField <= @now + 5184000000, 'sp-field-severity--good', 'sp-field-severity--low')))"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(@currentField <= @now + 1814400000,'Error', '')"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
}
```

Test result:
[image]